# Images not showing after Craft 2 to 3 migration

Tags: craft3

Hi upon migrating my site from Craft 2 to 3 I'm getting errors like this:

```
Twig Runtime Error – Twig_Error_Runtime
Variable "largeImage" does not exist.
```

"largeImage" refers to an image transform, this error happens with all image transforms where I've used an assets field to place a picture.

Also whenever I have embedded a picture inside an editor, this doesn't show either and the URL that is written out is:

```
 src="@baseUrl/images/image.png"
```

Clearly, something has gone wrong for @baseUrl to appear there. I've checked my base URL settings and it is set to "http://localhost:8888".

I don't know what else to try so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check that you actually have alias named `baseUrl` in your config.php file. It's not the same that you site's URL setting as set in control panel.

As for the Twig error, it would be helpful if you posted actual template code that throws the error.

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to fix this problem with some support, however I now have a few other problems as a cause of this and I think it is best to try and start a fresh post on it. I had to change the baseUrl which fixed the error but now have broken images across the website and duplicate folders in my assets. Argghh.